# error of running ASP.NET WEB API C# on Visual Studio 2013 win 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, windows-7

I am working on Visual Studio 2013 C# win 7.

I am doing ASP.NET WEB API development by following the instructions on

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api

At step 4 of Exercise 1: Create a Read-Only Web API, I got :

I pressed F5 to debug the application. The default home page for a Web API project did not appear.

I got error of

```
 Process with an Id of 14940 is not running.
```

Why I got this ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try cleaning solution and restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: After cleaning solution and restarting VS , I got new error:Server Error in '/' Application. Failed to start monitoring changes to '\\myPath\visual studio 2013\Projects\WebApplication6\example_WebApplication6\Views\Home' because the network BIOS command limit has been reached.